# Facet a Mutli-value(MVA) type field in sphinx

Tags: sphinx, facet

I have executed below query in sphinx,

```
select MVA_FIELD from mySphinxIndex  facet MVA_FIELD order by count(*) desc;
```

What I got is like,

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| MVA_FIELD                  | count(*) |
+----------------------------+----------+
|                            |      664 |
| 0                          |      536 |
| 13                         |      439 |
| 4,13                       |        8 |
| 19,13                      |        8 |
| 18,13,20                   |        8 |
| 8,17,18                    |        8 |
| 8,18,13                    |        8 |
| 8,15,18                    |        8 |
| 8,13,20                    |        7 |
| 17,13                      |        7 |
| 18,19,20                   |        7 |
| 8,17                       |        7 |
| 13,17,19                   |        7 |
| 11,6                       |        7 |
| 6,11,13                    |        7 |
| 15,18                      |        7 |
| 11,13,20                   |        7 |
| 11,13,17                   |        7 |
| 6,18,19                    |        6 |
| 7,20                       |        6 |
| 8,11,13                    |        6 |
| 13,17,20                   |        6 |
```

I want to get the count of each ids in MVA_FIELD. For example, I just want the count of 0, 4, 13,... each id separately. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly dont how how to do it with `FACET` suger, but with a normal `GROUP BY` query, would just use the `GROUPBY()` function when grouping by a MVA attribute

```
SELECT GROUPBY() AS value,COUNT(*) FROM mySphinxIndex GROUP BY MVA_FIELD ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

From the docs

- A special GROUPBY() function is also supported. It returns the GROUP BY key. That is particularly useful when grouping by an MVA value, in order to pick the specific value that was used to create the current group.

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter for your time but, you can see the output of the query you have suggested [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rByN4Eag-lldc2hcT06qu6V8QHghpi7H/view?usp=sharing). I still get a row for ID: 6 and a row for ID:(6 & 13 combined), do you have any suggestions?